# Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`Typeahead causing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeahead.js

Typeahead library copies properties from the target input, including `data-reactid`. So, as soon as copied `input` element has the same reactid, it caused error:

> Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`: .0.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.4.

I've tried to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but it causes bunch of errors. Is there another way to solve this? may be I need to prevent `data-reactid` from being copied somehow?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What type ahead library are you using? Whatever it is, yeah, it can't copy the react-id att without causing problems. There are plenty of react type components out there.